# Percentage Change Calculator is not working multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui

I have a percentage change calculator which is working functionally. But I need calculators for each table row. I'm calculating from a table cell and showing result in another cell for sorting purposes.

Problem is, my calculator is only working once in a same table row `.trCalculate` class. I need it multiple times. Most important thing is I need result in another table cell. Is this possible?

```css
 table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    font-family: arial;
  }
  
  th {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    padding: 5px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    font-size: 15px;
  }
  
  td {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    padding: 5px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    font-size: 15px;
  }
  
  input {
    margin: 3px 0;
    border: 1px solid #00f;
    height: 32px;
    padding-left: 7px;
    font-size: 18px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Calculator 01</th>
    <th>Calculator 02</th>
    <th>Calculator 01 Result</th>
    <th>Calculator 02 Result</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="trCalculate">
    <td>
      <input type="text" class="ChangeCalulator CalcFrom" value=""><br>
      <input type="text" class="CalcTo ChangeCalulator" value="1000">
    </td>
    <td>
      <h2 class="CalcResult"></h2>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" class="ChangeCalulator CalcFrom" value=""></br>
      <input type="text" class="CalcTo ChangeCalulator" value="2000">
    </td>
    <td>
      <h2 class="CalcResult"></h2>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<script>
  $(document).on("change keyup blur live", ".ChangeCalulator", function() { // For:- = Topper To Current %
    let formContainer = $(this).closest('.trCalculate')

    var first = Number($(formContainer).find('.CalcFrom').val()); // = Topper Price
    var second = Number($(formContainer).find('.CalcTo').val()); // = Current Price
    var minus = second - first; // 2000 - 1000 = {1000 = minus}
    var divide = (minus / first); // 1000 / 1000 = 1
    var multiply = divide * 100; // 1 * 100 = 100%
    $(formContainer).find('.CalcResult').val(Number(multiply).toFixed(2));
    $(formContainer).find('.CalcResult').text(Number(multiply).toFixed(2));
  });
</script>
```

Comment: A couple tips: 1) Your line break is malformed. You've written it as a closing tag. It shouldn't have a slash. A good editor will make this apparent. 2) You've misspelled "calculator" in many places as "calulator". This can cause confusion with other developers. 3) Don't communicate in code. Use plain English, as in "table cell" or "cell element", or use the editor to mark code as code. Raw HTML isn't displayed in posts.

Comment: Sorry for my English. I am not good in English. Because my native language is Malayalam (Kerala , India)

Comment: No need to apologize. Just make the corrections. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because your code is looking for single instances of each group of elements in the `tr`, even though there is two sets.

To avoid this issue you can instead use `closest()` to get the parent `td` instead of the `tr`, then use `next()` to get its sibling `td` to update the output:

```js
$(document).on("input change", ".change-calculator", e => {
  let $td = $(e.currentTarget).closest('td');
  let from = Number($td.find('.calc-from').val());
  let to = Number($td.find('.calc-to').val());
  let result = ((to - from) / from) * 100;
  $td.next().find('.calc-result').text(result.toFixed(2));
});
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  font-family: arial;
}

th {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 5px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  font-size: 15px;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 5px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  font-size: 15px;
}

input {
  margin: 3px 0;
  border: 1px solid #00f;
  height: 32px;
  padding-left: 7px;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Calculator 01</th>
    <th>Calculator 02</th>
    <th>Calculator 01 Result</th>
    <th>Calculator 02 Result</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" class="change-calculator calc-from" value=""><br />
      <input type="text" class="change-calculator calc-to" value="1000">
    </td>
    <td>
      <h2 class="calc-result"></h2>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" class="change-calculator calc-from" value=""><br />
      <input type="text" class="change-calculator calc-to" value="2000">
    </td>
    <td>
      <h2 class="calc-result"></h2>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Wow.. Excellet.. You are a highly tallented developer.. Thank you very much.. :) :)

Comment: Please add `"change keyup blur live"` to this code.. Because I need change event/function with it

Comment: It can be added to the event list in the first argument to `on()`. I've done it for you. I left `input` in though as it covers the other events.

Comment: Thanks..
`$(document).on("change keyup blur live", "input", ".change-calculator", e => {`
Is this correct ?

Comment: Yeah, that'll work

Comment: Hi.. Do you know the answer of this question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73630166/tablesorter-is-not-sorting-calculation-result-columns-jquery-javascript